# import error when trying to import tensorflow in python3

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I'm getting this error when trying to import tensorflow `ImportError: cannot import name 'tensorflow' from 'opt_einsum.backends' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/opt_einsum/backends/__init__.py)`.

I've installed it using pip and it's version 2.2.0.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, removing and reinstalling opt_einsum worked for me, e.g.:

```
pip uninstall opt_einsum
pip install opt_einsum
```

If this doesn't work, check if tensorflow.py is located in the /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/opt_einsum/backends/
folder